# why socket.recv() on python3 return value that lost the last byte?

Tags: python-3.x, tcpdump

So I have python code like this to send and receive UDP packet to a port

```
  s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
  UDP_IP = '1.0.0.45'
  UDP_PORT = 8100
  s.connect((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
  r = s.send(ethernet_packet + payload)
  data = s.recv(1024)
  print(data)
```

Packet sent successfully, in the `tcpdump`, the udp packet that i received is [image]

But the data that received is printed like this: `b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08\x80\x04\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x009'`
the last byte should be "x39", 3 is missing for some reason, does anyone know why?
Thx in adv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. If python can represent a byte in a bytes object as ASCII, it will. b'9' is just b'\x39', but python prefers ASCII for readability.

```py
>>> b"\x39"
b'9'
```

The Python docs for [string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings) indicate that ASCII characters and characters with hex values are valid in a bytes string.

Comment: got it, i use print(str(encode(data, "hex"), "utf-8")) instead, it fixed. thx